# How to select a single TextBlock in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have this `DataTemplate` in my WPF application.

When I click a button I need to get `TextBlock Name="titleCategory"` and change its color.

At the moment I am not able to select the `TextBlock`.

Could you provide me a simple solution?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CategoriesSelectedDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"
                CornerRadius="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="Transparent" >
            <TextBlock Name="titleCategory" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="{Binding CapitalizedDescription, FallbackValue=Category}"
                       Foreground="Red"
                       />
        </Border>
        <!-- 1L main menu HOVER -->
        <Custom:SurfaceListBox
            d:LayoutOverrides="Width"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Shops}"
            ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ShopUnselectedSurfaceListDataTemplate}"
            Grid.RowSpan="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            SelectionChanged="shopListBox_SelectionChanged"
            ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CategoriesSurfaceListBoxItemStyle}"
            SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Do it MVVM way. Bind `Foregorund` with some property and on button click set that property. You need not to worry about getting the TextBlock.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with this code

```
            var elem = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)elem.FindName("titleCategory");
            myTextBlock.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow;
```